# JS equivalent to C++ .at()

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object:

```
var foo = {'bar1': {'baz1':1}};
```

And I try to access `foo['bar2']['baz2']`. If I was just trying to access `foo['bar2']`, JS would return `undefined`. But because I'm trying to get the next property after the undefined `bar2`, JS throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz2' of undefined.`

Is there some automatic accessor for an object that first checks if `baz2` exists in `foo` before trying to call its properties? I know I could use a try/catch block or an if statement, but I was hoping for a function along the lines of C++'s [`array::at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/at/), that would check for me.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: `if (foo['bar2']) { ... }` ?

Comment: @Avitus isn't `indexOf` only for arrays?

Comment: @hkpeprah That works fine and is what I have now, I'm just wondering if there's some access method that would check for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own pretty easily:

```
function at(obj, property) {
  var props = property.split('.');
  for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
    obj = obj[props[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}

var foo = {'bar1': {'baz1':1}};
console.log(at(foo, 'bar1.baz1'));
// => 1
console.log(at(foo, 'bar2.baz2'));
// => undefined
```

Comment: Alright, too bad it's not built in already. Thanks, this is what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind this is ONLY for objects, like the one you have shown, and NOT for arrays (ie [0, 1, 2]) but my favorite is this one:

```
if ('bar1' in foo)
```

This is even useful for, say, HTML5 feature detection.

```
if ('localStorage' in window)
```

I could give you one for arrays too, but I feel like the more logical thing would be to compare its length to a given index. And...not insert undefined values into arrays. Y'know. =p

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
if("bar2" in foo) {
   //do stuff with foo['bar2']
}
```

or you can check to see if `foo['bar2']` is `undefined`:

```
if(typeof foo['bar2'] !== "undefined") {
    //do stuff with foo['bar2']
}
```

Also, what you're working with are objects and not arrays (well, they're associative arrays, but also objects in JavaScript).

Comment: What's the benefit of these over `if (foo["bar2"]) { . . .`?

Comment: `if (foo["bar2"])` can fail spuriously if it maps to `false`, `""`, `0`, or `NaN`. Typically you just want to see if something is defined or not, but using this pattern evaluates the *truthyness* of `foo["bar2"]` and not whether it is defined.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point . . . so if, for some reason (and, in this example, it looks like it would be highly unexpected) the object were `var foo = {"bar2": false}`, it would return `false`, throwing off the check for "definition".  Gotchya . . . thanks.   :)

Answer (score 0):

`foo['bar2'] && foo['bar2']['baz2']` will do the trick as well.